# Why does my custom prompt not show in Ubuntu/Bash on Windows 10?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I added this to my `~/.bash_profile` in "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (and I have `git` installed):

```
# Get the Git branch
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

# Custom bash prompt
#
# Includes custom character for the prompt, path, and Git branch name.
#
# Source: kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html
export PS1="\n\[$(tput bold)\]\[$(tput setaf 5)\] \[$(tput setaf 6)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 3)\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

When entering a new bash shell, I don't see this change in effect. What am I doing wrong?

My `~/.bashrc` is untouched and at its default.

If I add the code above to `~/.bashrc`, it works. But I don't want to clobber with customizations.

Comment: It's happening because the shell you're opening is not a login shell and so `~/.bash_profile` is not sourced. You should put it in `~/.bashrc` (as you noticed it works there) - that's the normal place to set the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

In "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows", the opened shell is not a "login shell", which means `.bash_profile` isn't being read, as mentioned by @Zanna (thank you!).

You can use `shopt` to see whether your'e in a "login shell" or not:

```
shopt login_shell
```

Since I wish to keep things tidy and put customizations into their own files, I'm now sourcing a custom file from `.bashrc`:

```
  . ~/.bashrc_customizations
```